# How to expand variables in a string containing

Tags: bash, typeset

I have a bash function whose body I retrieve and expand the variable inside.

Here's the code in my bash script:

```
my_var=my_value
my_fn() {
    echo $myvar
}
```

What `typeset -f my_fn` gives me:

```
my_fn() {
    echo $myvar
}
```

What I need :

```
my_fn() {
    echo my_value
}
```

How can I expand variables appearing in my_fn ? I can store the result in a string or a function if needed.

I can't manually expand all variables because the function may use a lot of variables. Also I can't use `envsubst` because the variables are not exported.

What would solve my issue is to expand the variables at function definition time, not during its execution.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you need to do a bit more clearly. Ideally, give us the full `ssh` command you want to run.

Comment: I removed the bit about ssh that is not really relevant here, and added a bit. Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/13151031/10622916

Comment: @Bodo already tried all that, but that needs a whole bunch of escaping in the function declaration. The whole point of using typeset -f is to have real bash code and not a string.

Comment: I don't understand your comment about `typeset -f`. Run `my_var=my_value`, `eval "my_fn() { echo $my_var; }"` then `typeset -f my_fn`. This will print the expected output from your question. This also works with a multi-line function definition. If this is not sufficient, please explain in your question why this does not solve the problem in your use case. Maybe then you should extend your example to make this clear.

Comment: I mean that I want the function declaration to be "real", not in a string, partly for syntax coloration and linting (shellcheck). Currently the script uses heredocs to declare this kind of function. The solution you're proposing is to write the function body inside a string so that unfortunately doesn't work.

Comment: @Salamandar **Please add all clarification or requested information to the question**. Don't use comments to add information. Your example seems to be too simple. Please explain your use case. Why do you need variable substitution at the time of the function definition? What do you want to achieve with this? This might be an XY problem. Maybe there is a different solution for your real problem.